# Cannot create authenticated Servant client that provides a session cookie

Tags: haskell, session-cookies, servant

I'm trying to create a Servant client for a basic API with session/cookie authentication; yet, I get a type-check error about a missing `BearerAuthNotEnabled` instance.

Here ist my API:

```hs
import           RIO
import qualified Data.Aeson                    as J
import           Servant                       ( (:>), (:<|>) )
import qualified Servant                       as SV
import qualified Servant.Auth.Server           as AS
import qualified Servant.Client                as SC

-- Contents of the session cookie
data User = User
  { username :: !Text
  , email :: !Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance J.ToJSON User
instance J.FromJSON User
instance AS.ToJWT User
instance AS.FromJWT User

-- An endpoint that requires authentication.
type ProtectedEndpoint = "protected" :> SV.Get '[SV.JSON] Text

-- The API with authentication wrapped around the protected endpoint.
type Api = (AS.Auth '[AS.Cookie] User :> ProtectedEndpoint)
```

And here is my attempt to create a client:

```hs
apiProxy :: Proxy Api
apiProxy = Proxy

-- Let Servant generate HTTP clients.
protectedClient :: AC.Token -> SC.ClientM Text
protectedClient = SC.client apiProxy
```

Upon compilation, I get the following instance error, of which I can't make much sense:

```
    • No instance for Servant.Auth.Client.Internal.BearerAuthNotEnabled
        arising from a use of ‘SC.client’
    • In the expression: SC.client apiProxy
      In an equation for ‘protectedClient’:
          protectedClient = SC.client apiProxy
```

Am I configuring the Servant client in the correct to pass along a session cookie?

*Update:* Adding token authentication (JWT) to the mix resolves the issue. I.e., if I declare the API type as

```hs
type Api = (AS.Auth '[AS.Cookie, AS.JWT] User :> ProtectedEndpoint)
-- instead of
-- type Api = (AS.Auth '[AS.Cookie] User :> ProtectedEndpoint)
```

Comment: it seems the Client library does not include a the right instance for Cookie (which is not that surprising - maybe add one for `Bearer`) - as described [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-auth-client-0.4.1.0/docs/Servant-Auth-Client-Internal.html#t:HasBearer) it seems to only include `HasBearer` if you have an `Auth` with either `JWT` or `Bearer`. My guess is that the `BearerAuthNotEnabled` is there to *fail* ?

Comment: `HasBearer` is a type family, and `BearerAuthNotEnabled` is one possible result: `HasBearer '[] = BearerAuthNotEnabled`. However, I do not understand how my code end up in the empty-list cases. To my understanding, the type-level list in question here is `'[AS.Cookie]`, which is not empty. But my understanding of type-level programming is very limited.

Comment: you are correct - if you look at the other "cases" (it works almost like a normal case ... of) you see that it looks for `Bearer` and `JWT` - and the place it looks is a list of `auths` (you find it bellow at the *orphan instances* section) - there is no *case* for `Cookie` so it falls through to `BearerAuthNotEnabled` - but this one is a rather *pointless*  class - there cannot be an instance of it - and all other found constraints are empty (`()` is an empty constraint too) - so this is really just there to make sure you use one of the above `Auth` methods

Comment: Hm, is it a bug that `Cookie` is not one of the cases here? After all, the library explicitly supports cookie authentication, and has an entire section in the README about using it on the server. And why does it work if I construct a client for the login endpoint separately (see my update to the question)?

Comment: If you only use the `Api.Login` you never have a `Auth auths a :> ...` in your API-Type and so the `HasBearer` constraint-type-computation is never triggered

Comment: Ah, so it's about the request header, not the response header. Thanks!

Comment: I did not check but you could go to the github(?) for that library and see the issues - I would assume that for a Haskell-Client they just did not implement it (yet?)